# Embedding a song on a web site

Tags: html, embed

I am trying to embed this song (http://radio3.cbc.ca/play/hdmdc/playlist/Week-1) (shortened link: http://r3.ca/09bP) on my web page but I can't get a code that actually works. (This is the only web site I can find this song on). Help me!

Comment: Do you have the actual audio file or are you trying to link to their website..?

Comment: Are you sure the publisher has granted permission for you to embed it in your webpage? There's an MP3 steam button, but it's disabled. I went to the next tack, and its stream button is enabled, but the stream is invalid (possibly because I don't live in Canada). I really don't think they mean for you to embed their tracks on your webpage.

Answer (score 2):

You can't steal music from another website. I don't think the radio station would appreciate that. You can link to the page with the player like they want you to do.

Find another site that has an embeddable player if you really want it be on your own website.

Comment: I've done it before so I know it can work. (It's for a school site, not sharing or charging)

Comment: That site is the ONLY one that has the song!

Comment: I've tried EVERY possible code combination I could find on the Internet. Nothing works. I embedded the song last year using a site called Zappyhost but it's gone now and the code I saved doesn't work anymore. (It's for a Geography virtual school site so the song is the perfect music to open the page to)

Comment: I agree with Lèse majesté. This song is not meant to be embedded. You can try to extract the flash player from the page code if you want, but I'm sure there is considerable script instantiation required as well.

Comment: How about first calling the publisher up and asking if you can embed the song on your school webpage and then buying the song and embedding it?

Comment: The thing is, a year ago, this code worked! 
<embed src="http://www.indyish.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/05-geography.mp3" highQuality="true" width="450" height="300" align="center" name="MySpaceMusicPlayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed>
<br /><p style="font-family:verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:10px;"><a href="http://www.zappyhost.com">Domain Names</a></p>.

Comment: Thanks! I did it but it only linked to the site (and whatever was playing at the time) not the specific song. Then I inserted the song link (in place of indyish url) and it connects to the actual song now. Problem is, you have to click the "play" link. How do I get it to play when the site opens up?

With regards to the legality, I'm exposing an obscure French Canadian duo to America's youth. They might actually sell a few CDs because of this!

Comment: So if I can just change the code above to make it play on opening, I'm set. Thanks!